# Are there any alternative devices to routers?

Tags: routing, networking, network-core

I am not talking about the router used at home to access Internet .

I am talking about devices used in the network core.

I want to know if there are alternative devices, if any, used for **forwarding** and **routing** in any network .

Comment: Routers are what route packets between networks. There are devices that may be called something else that route packets between networks (e.g. a layer-3 switch), but, internally, there is also a router in the device.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you need to forward between different L2 segments/L3 subnets then any device actually doing that is a router by definition.

So, there's no alternative to a router (which may be a classic router, software on a host, a layer-3 switch, a routing firewall, SDN hardware, ...).

Comment: If you design the whole network core to work on layer 2 then you use switches (which are layer-2 routers but nobody calls them that)

Answer (score 2):

Routers may take many forms, such as a traditional hardware box that takes packets in, and forwards/routes them, but also, a general-purpose PC that takes packets in, and forwards/routes them. A "layer-3 switch" also does routing.

As long as it is doing routing and forwarding, it can be said to be a router (based on the definition of the *functionality*), even though it may also be a general-purpose PC (for example).

Answer (score 1):

Technically, Router can be replaced with a router only. Practically, any devices which has routing capabilities can be used replacing a router.

In your case, you can use a Firewall which will enable you for routing as well as other features like security policies, DHCP Services etc.

Hope, This is helpful !!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Multilayer switch (layer3 switch) and firewall are used as alternative for routers

But in L3 multi layered  switch NAting  configuration is not feasible